# USB stick no longer mountable

Tags: usb, mount

I have an 8GB usb stick I wanted to burn an image of androidx86 to. It had data on it, so I tried to format it (after backing up the data first). Initially, I was going to use Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator to burn the image, and it seemed like I could use any image, but it wouldn't let me change the label of the drive, so I exited the program. The label still ended up getting changed somehow, and the usb stick won't mount to my system anymore. I even tried formatting the stick with fdisk, but I get an error when trying to mount it from the gui file manager. Out put of `dmesg | tail` is:

`[  211.660920] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  211.661192] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 15656960 512-byte logical blocks: (8.02 GB/7.47 GiB)
[  211.661585] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  211.661592] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  211.662096] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  211.662105] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  211.665272]  sdb: sdb1
[  211.666702] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  212.341785] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
[  236.974990] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.`

[picture of the mount error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1ZWX.png)

I guess the system is trying to mount it as a cd, even though it shouldn't be formatted that way. Is there any way I can repair this? I don't really know what happened to it.

Comment: "fdisk" manages partition information (for example deleting a DOS partition and adding a Linux partition).  You need other programs to format a partition.  If the image you want to "burn" onto the USB drive is an ISO image, then it should have all this information within it (partitions & formatting).  Beware, ISO images need to be "burned" onto media that is at least as large as the media where the image was taken from.  That is, you can not burn an image of a 16GB partition onto an 8GB device.

Comment: I've burned ISOs before. I'm just not sure how to do it now since my system won't even mount the stick. It looks like it thinks the stick is some kind of CD, but it isn't. I don't even know if using dd on the command line would work.

Comment: You don't want the mass storage device mounted when you "burn an ISO image" onto it.  That's because the computer mounting the device needs to know the type of the partition (NTFS, EXT4, FAT...).  And the point of an ISO image is to write everything including the type of the partition.   So no, you don't want the device mounted.

Comment: Looking back on the issue, I have to wonder if I may have skipped a step somewhere in the whole formatting process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Disks program, I was able to reformat the usb stick so that it's actually recognized as a usb stick and not a CD. It was apparently formatted with ISO9660 as a filesystem. Disks was able to mount the usb stick in its malformed state, allowing me to delete the pre-existing partition and reformat it as FAT32. Mounting the drive from the gui file manager also works now.

Comment: Cloning from an Ubuntu iso file to a USB pendrive or memory card will create a bootable drive, that can be used to run Ubuntu live and to install Ubuntu. There will be a ISO9660 file system, and it is correct. *The problem is that the tool you used to analyze (and repair) does not understand what it is looking at.* You can install and use mkusb to restore a USB stick or memory card to a standard storage device (format) with an MSDOS partition table and a partition with a FAT32 file system. See the following link and links from it, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Answer (score 0):

I also had a Sandisk Ultra USB 3.0 16GB which died and would no longer mount in linux no matter what I did, also tried windows. Was previously EXT4 formatted before it died.

Anyway, happy to say it has been brought back to life with the commands from [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/repair-corrupted-usb-drive-linux/) Here is a summary:

1. Plug in the device and run `lsblk` to find out its name. My device was turned out to be `sdd` could tell from the sizes.
2. Run `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd` This took 25 minutes and didn't offer any feedback till it was finished.
3. Run `sudo mkfs.ext4  /dev/sdd`

Comment: It is usually enough to wipe (overwrite) the first megabyte (to be precise: mibibyte) in order to remove the data is confusing your partitioning tool. And it is much faster than to overwrite the whole drive. Furthermore, it causes less wear of the memory cells.